# BindingAdapter not recognized as applicable to property with generics

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-databinding

Matching `ObservableList<Subclass>` to `@BindingAdapter` declaration with `ObservableList<Baseclass>` behaves in a strange way.

---

I am trying out the android databinding library in context of MVVM and stumbled upon a behavior which I do not understand and have not found any resources for so far.

The setup:

```
Min SDK: 19
Target SDK: 26
Build Tools Version: 27.0.1
```

I want to bind an `android.databinding.ObservableList<Model>` to a `RecyclerView` by using a custom binding adapter which takes the list, wraps it into a generic `RecyclerView.Adapter` and assigns it to the `RecyclerView`.

My binding adapter is set up like this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"items"})
public static void bindAdapterWithDefaultBinder(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                                @Nullable ObservableList<Model> items){
... implementation ...
}
```

My viewmodel has the following property:

```
public final ObservableList<Repo> repos = new ObservableArrayList<>();
```

`Repo` in this case implements the interface `Model`.

And the layout file contains

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:items="@{vm.repos}"
            />
```

When compiling I receive the following error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:items' with parameter type android.databinding.ObservableList<_my-package-name_.Repo> on android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.
```

So I thought this has something to do with the type `Repo` not being recognized as a valid substitute for `Model` in the binding converter declaration. Strange, but sure enough - if I change the declaration to use `ObservableList<Repo> items` the code compiles fine and works. But this is not a viable solution for me since this would force me to write a binding adapter for every single model or view model type I intend to use. So after some experimenting I found a different solution:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:items="@{(Object)vm.repos}"
            />
```

Now this solution compiles with the `ObservableList<Model> items` adapter declaration and propagates all change events correctly at runtime. So basically I cast the `ObservableList<Repo>` to `Object` and it is interpreted as matching the adapter definition. What?????

Keep in mind all of this happens at compile time where the exact types are known to the code generator so no type erasure is happening.

**So in order my questions are:**

- Why does the first implementation fail exaclty?
- Why does casting to `Object` resolve the problem?
- Since this looks like an ugly hack to me - what would be the correct way to implement this behaviour?

P.S.:

For more context on the issue I am basically working my way through this example code which I found to be a great source of inspiration: https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md

But notice how the author cheekily "casts" all his model objects to the base class type to avoid this exact problem [here](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#create-itemlistingviewmodel-for-our-page).

Answer (score 1):

That's because `List` is not covariant in Java. That means that `List<Subclass>` is not `List<Baseclass>` so there is no reason for binding engine to consider your adapter. You need:

```
@BindingAdapter({"items"})
public static <T extends Model> void bindAdapterWithDefaultBinder(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                            @Nullable ObservableList<T> items){
```

and generics all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove braces to be like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("items")   
public static void bindAdapterWithDefaultBinder(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @Nullable ObservableList<Model> items) {
... implementation ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The code in the post is a simplified version of the original code where the actual annotation is `@BindingAdapter(value = {"items", "viewProvider", "itemActionResponder"}, requireAll = false)` so it is not possible to remove the braces here. This does also not change the behavior as the instantiated annotation has `String[]` of values and ommiting the braces is just a shorthand for adding a single element here.

Comment: No, not yet. As is posited in the question, there is an ugly workaround for that. But I still do not understand what is happening here and why. Disclaimer: I have not tested this with newer versions of the APIs involved.